# CounterCache CakePHP for existing model

Tags: cakephp

Is there a way to initialize the CounterCache for existing data? I refactor my code to use it and indeed if I insert a record it'll update the data, but until then it shows 0 which will break other functionality. I thought about writing a script to do the work, but thought there might be a trick?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 3):

There is not built-in functionality that would magically update all your models if this is what you are looking for.

You can however relatively easily update the counter caches manually using [**`Model::updateCounterCache()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Model.html#_updateCounterCache), check how the `Model` uses it on save or delete.

Here's a basic example, assuming an `Article hasMany Comment / Comment belongsTo Article` association.

```
$article = ClassRegistry::init('Article');

foreach(array_keys($article->find('list')) as $id) {
    $article->Comment->updateCounterCache(array(
        $article->Comment->belongsTo['Article']['foreignKey'] => $id
    ));
}
```

This would update all configured counters for all articles in the database (keep in mind that depending on the size of your DB this can be quite a heavy task).

Comment: Thanks it worked like a magic :-) not sure how I missed the updateCounterCache, probably had to check the cake implementation.